# AWS CodeBuild with Multi Docker Containers: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, build, dockerfile, aws-codebuild

so I am trying to deploy my multi-docker container(Frontend, Backend, and Nginx containers) application in AWS BeansTalk. I am using CodeBuild to build the docker images using `buildspec.yml` file. The build fails when trying to build the first container(containerizing frontend application). Kindly refer to the image attached for the error details.

[image: The]

It is basically saying could not find the Dockerfile in the client directory but the funny thing is that it exists and it works as expected locally when I build the containers with docker-compose.

Here is the project directory:

[image]

buildspec.yml file:

[image]

Comment: can you post buildspec ?

Comment: @ArunK I just updated my question with the buildspec.

Comment: Just add a `ls` command before line 17to see the current directory contents. I think you are in the wrong directory

Comment: this is the result of the `ls` commend: Dockerrun.aws.json
README.md
buildspec.yml
client
docker-compose.yml
nginx
server

Comment: I am starting to believe you :).  can you do `ls client` and confirm the file is inside.

Comment: It is empty. I am not sure where I have exactly messed up haha

Comment: Guessed so :). goto your source repository and see if the contents inside client directory are committed.

Comment: I think that is the issue. There is an issue with my client folder. there is a white arrow on the folder after I pushed it to GitHub. Thanks a lot Arun for your time!

Comment: No. Can you directly check on github for the existence of the file

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others, The reason for the error is that the Dockerfile is missing in the location. Make sure you have the `DockerFile` inside the directory (./client in this case). It has to be exactly spelled as `Dockerfile`. If it's not, check the source repo and ensure that the Dockerfile file is committed.